# Can a modified Ubuntu flash drive installation be installed on another system?

Tags: flash, drive

Would it be possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to a flash drive, install all the updates and desired apps such as flash and THEN install it updates and all to another system? I'm hoping I can save a lot of time and repetition by doing it all once on the flash and then maybe applying a few tweaks after I install it on an actual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using remastersys :

http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html

You can create live iso of your existing system. So install all the required packages on your Ubuntu and then take a iso using remastersys. Then using startup disk, you can create bootable usb from this iso.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add the following line in the end of the file:

```
deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remastersys
sudo apt-get install remastersys-gui
sudo apt-get install remastersys-gtk
```

To run the remastersys in GUI mode, type the following command:

```
sudo remastersys-gui
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I don't know my way around linux enough though to understand all the instructions. I don't know what "synaptic" is, "apt line", "oneiric", or the difference between precise and quantal main. They mention a couple of methods that have a general user interface. Which of those would be best for the novice user?

Comment: edit your /etc/apt/sources.list file. Add the following line in the end of the file.

Comment: Please refer the answer

Comment: I've ordered a bigger flash drive. My 4gb wasn't big enough to install the updates and apps on. Thanks for your help!